# SKStoreReviewController requestReview does not work in iMessage extension

Tags: ios, storekit, imessage-extension, skstorereviewcontroller

I tried calling `SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()` in my iMessage extension, but it never shows the UI. I know the system controls whether or not this appears, but based on the documentation (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/2851536-requestreview) it seems like it should appear at least once.

If I move the call to the containing app, it works as expected. The entire user experience is based out of the imessage extension, so this is not really a viable solution

Comment: got the same problems, did you solve it @adamF ?

Comment: nope, I ended up deep linking to the app store through an ugly jump from imessage -> containing app -> app store page -> app store review draft page. It'd be great if apple updated this

Comment: Yeah, for that would be great if they will support this.